# TableView footer not scrolling with content

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit

In my app, I have a view in the footer of my tableview (tableview.tablefooterview) that doesn't scroll with the content. [image: crappy]

No matter what I do, it gets pushed down with the addition of a cell.
Here is the initialization code:

```
  CGRect footerRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200);
footerview2.frame = footerRect;

self.tableView.backgroundColor = self.footerview.backgroundColor;
self.tableView.tableFooterView = footerview2;
```

Comment: How many section is in your table view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding section footer. Implement the tableview delegate:

```
-(UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return footerview2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

add this method in you view controller

```
- (CGFloat) tableView : (UITableView  *) tableView heightForFooterInSection : ( NSInteger ) section
```